# Can the nested try except block in python be simplified

Tags: python, try-catch

everyone, my python code is something like this:

```
try:
    foo1()
except FooError1:
    try:
        foo2()
    except FooError2:
        dosth()
raise raisesth()
```

I wonder if there is a try-except support for multi conditions or compound conditions in python, thus my code could be simplified as:

```
try:
    foo1() 
    foo2()
except FooError1 and FooError2:
    dosth()
raise raisesth()
```

Thanks!

Comment: No it can't. They run `foo2()` under different conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

I assume you want `dosth` called if `foo1()` or `foo2()` raise an exception you want to handle in `dosth()`, like in your second code block.

```
try:
    foo1() 
    foo2()
except (FooError1, FooError2):
    dosth()
raise raisesth()
```

As you may ask a `and` condition in your `except` statement I remember you an exception **must** be handled as soon as it raises or execution will stop so you can't tell the interpreter to go ahead waiting for `FooError2` to come...

Comment: This does not have the same behavior as the first example.

Comment: @neurino: This works like **or**, is not it? He asks for **and**.

Comment: @Fenikso: got it, you are right. Then I hope the OP explains under which precise conditions wants `dosth` executed...

Comment: Thx all! After I checked the python doc, I realized the except can hold a tuple multi conditions. This works like a **or** condition.

Comment: @demoslam - yes, but it won't behave the same way you wrote in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

Exception **and** ;-).

```
def foo1():
    return 1/0

def foo2():
    return s

def do_something():
    print("Yes!")

def exception_and(functions, exceptions, do_something):
        try:
            functions[0]()
        except exceptions[0]:
            if len(functions) == 1:
                do_something()
            else:
                exception_and(functions[1:], exceptions[1:], do_something)

# ================================================================
exception_and([foo1, foo2], [ZeroDivisionError, NameError], do_something)

# Behaves the same as:

try:
    foo1()
except ZeroDivisionError:
    try:
        foo2()
    except NameError:
        do_something()
```

Comment: Can be simplified via `zip()` and `for`/`else`.